# Apple Pay wallet screen (PKAddPaymentPassViewController) is not coming properly in my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, credit-card, applepay, wallet

I'm implementing In-App card provisioning in my app. UI is not coming properly it's coming in zoom state like this can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue.

[image: On click of Add Card to wallet]

[image]

To present this `PKPaymentPassViewController` using the below code with `requestConfiguration` data. Same is working fine in a demo app which I created a new project. My app is not fully UI compatible with iPhone 6 & later is that the issue?

```
PKAddPaymentPassViewController *vc = [[PKAddPaymentPassViewController alloc] initWithRequestConfiguration:request delegate:self];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: can you please check my question once again I clearly explained @Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved this is due to the status bar. In my application is not using the status bar.

To resolve this issue I'm unhiding the status bar at the time of invoking the wallet and hiding when I came back to my app from the wallet.